# Google translate formula not working properly in array function

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-translate, flatten

When I was using as such it was working perfectly.

```
GOOGLETRANSLATE(V2,"en","ms")
```

But, now I change it to array function its not translating ROW 2 and below instead its translating ROW 1 which contain the header(Director Designation)

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS(ROW(AE:AE)=1,"Director Designation (BM)",A:A="","",TRUE,GOOGLETRANSLATE(V:V,"en","ms")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GOOGLETRANSLATE` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`. you can either hardcode it:

```
={GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2, "en", "ms");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(A3, "en", "ms");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(A4, "en", "ms")}
```

[image]

---

but it would be a waste of time typing the whole column by hand so you can use:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA("={"&TEXTJOIN(";", 1, "GOOGLETRANSLATE(A"&
 ROW(A2:A)&", ""en"", ""ms"")")&"}")}
```

[image]

---

or you can try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(GOOGLETRANSLATE(QUERY(
 FILTER(A2:A&".", A2:A<>""),,9^9), "en", "ms"), "."))))
```

[image]

---

you may also resolve it via script or with API calls: **https://developers.google.com/apps-script**

Comment: The code below didn't work well. 

```=ArrayFormula(IFS(ROW(AE:AE)=1,"Director Designation (BM)",A:A="","",TRUE,INDEX(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(GOOGLETRANSLATE(QUERY(
 FILTER(V2:V&".", V2:V<>""),,9^9), "en", "ms"), "."))))))```

Comment: So I tried like what you suggested and hard code it. It works for now. May be later I try to see if any other better way to do it.

Comment: @Kugen `IFS` does not work with arrays well

Comment: Owh.. Any better way for me to improve it? I have been using IFS for all my arrays.

Comment: This works as I intended. Hard code did work but it has its limitation.
```=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(GOOGLETRANSLATE(QUERY(
 FILTER(A2:A&".", A2:A<>""),,9^9), "en", "ms"), "."))))```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

good news, we have new functions so now it can be done easily with:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:A100; LAMBDA(x; GOOGLETRANSLATE(x; "en"; "ms"))))
```

[image]